# How can I change body background color depending on active slide?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am using Swiper (no jQuery, pure JavaScript) to display 11 slides. I want to change the body `background-color` depending on which slide the user is on.

This code works fine, but when the slider restarts it keeps the colour of the last slide instead of restarting from the first one:

```
 swiper.on('transitionEnd', function(e) {
     if (this.activeIndex == 1) {
       document.querySelector("body").style.background = '#F4F1C1';
     }
     if (this.activeIndex == 2) {
       document.querySelector("body").style.background = '#DCDDDE';
     }
     if (this.activeIndex == 3) {
       document.querySelector("body").style.background = '#ECEBDF';
     }
     if (this.activeIndex == 4) {
       document.querySelector("body").style.background = '#F2E3E3';
     }
     if (this.activeIndex == 5) {
       document.querySelector("body").style.background = '#D0EFF0';
     }
 });
```

On **[this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1ru4ejm/1/)** you can see that after slide 11, the slider goes back to slide 1 but the colour is still `#999999` rather than `#F4F1C1`.

Why is the index not restarting?

Comment: Optimize your code little  bit https://jsfiddle.net/owj8vy2c/2/

Comment: I can also notice that library you've used might be broken. Active index is not the same after the same transition. Sometimes it shows 0 for first element, some other time it is 1, other situation is that I received 12 as active index even though there are only 11 items in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swiper shifts its array index by 1. As seen here in the documentation

[image]

So you're *correctly* starting from index `1` but not accounting for the 11th item at index `12`

https://swiperjs.com/api/

You can use `this.realIndex` to get the correct index of the looped item according to the documentation.